# what is the meaning of this element $\varphi(f|_Y)?$

Tags: functional-analysis, symbolic-computation

I have some confusion in symbolics  .

My confusion is given below marked in red colour

[image]

what is the meaning  of this element $\varphi(f|_Y)?$

My main confusion about the symbolics is  $(f|_Y)$?

Comment: $f\vert_Y$ is the restriction of $f$ to domain $Y$, since your $f$ is defined to have domain $X\supset Y$.  If it makes you feel better, $f\vert_Y=i_Y^* f$ where $i_Y\colon Y\to X$ is the inclusion and $i_Y^*\colon X'\to Y'$ is the induced dual map $i_Y^*f=f\circ i_Y$.

Comment: The symbol is not $(f\mid_Y)$ but rather $f\mid_Y$. The bracket belongs to $\phi$, i.e. we have $\phi(g)$ with $g=f\mid_Y$.